# SSDT - pre-build automation - setting 'buildAction' flag for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I am wondering if anyone has an example of setting a Pre-Build Event (project properties, Build events) on an SSDT project so that we can change a files 'Build Action' from 'build' to None given a project configuration.

Something like:  *if $configuration is x then set buildAction = 'none' on abc.sql else set buildAction = 'build'*

Regards

Comment: No, it can't be done in exactly that way. If you describe your problem, there might be just another solution of it

Comment: Two stored procs that have the same name, but different implementations based on environment - tables are different. Currently have to manually mark as build - but want to automate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have different implementations of the same stored procedure, then you'll probably have 2 options:

- Create conditional logic inside SP. You'll need to define variable value when publishing and in the code you'll have something like:

```
    IF ('$(EnvVar)' = 'PROD')
    BEGIN
       -- code needed to be executed in PROD
    END
    IF ('$(EnvVar)' = 'DEV')
    BEGIN
       -- code needed to be executed in DEV
    END
```

- Create 2 (or you might need more) projects that would have that single procedure (or set of objects) with different implementations. Then add the reference to your main project with an option "The same database". Then create different publish profiles in the projects and use proper connection strings there.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.   This is something that I tried - the issue is that it did not build/compile as the tables in one environment do not exist in the other (the stored procs are being used as interfaces with different implementations).   The other thing attempted was to use the post-deploy script and conditional include - however, I struck an issue with batch statements.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using a pre-build event to copy a clone of the stored procs into the correct location depending on the build setting.  So I have marked the above as an answer as well.

I could have also used a .tt file to generate the stored procedure at build time.